udisksctl: get loop device and mount point without resorting to parsing localized output?
udisksctl is my tool of choice when dealing with file system images (recent example, but I've been doing this all over the place).
The dance typically looks like
fallocate -l ${img_size} filesystem.img
mkfs.${fs} filesystem.img

# Set up loop device as regular user
loopback=$(udisksctl loop-setup -b "${img_file}" | sed 's/.* \([^ ]*\)\.$/\1/')

# Mount as regular user
mounted=$(udisksctl mount -b "${loopback}" | sed 's/^.* \([^ ]*\)$/\1/')

# Do the testing/benchmarking/file management
# e.g.:
cp -- "${files[@]}" "${mounted}"

Quite frankly, I have a bad feeling about the way I parse the output of udisksctl; these are clearly human-aimed strings:

Mapped file filesystem.img as /dev/loop0.
Mounted /dev/loop1 at /run/media/marcus/E954-81FB


And I don't think anyone considers their actual format "API". So, my scripts might break in the future! (Not to mention the nasal demons I invite if the image file name contains line breaks.)
udisksctl doesn't seem to have a "porcelain" output option or similar. Is there an existing method that does udisksctl's job of loopback mounting with user privilege through udisks2, with a proper, unambiguous output?

Time for an RFE, apparently ;-)

I feel your pain... I also love the sudo-less power of udisksctl, I use UDisks2 in several snippets and projects, and I also hate how "machine-unfriendly" its output is.
That said, one approach I'm leaning towards to is not to parse the output of udisksctl mount,loop-*,..., use it for actions only, and leave parsing to udisksctl info, udevadm or even lsblk -lnpb (which can even have JSON output if you're willing to use jq!).
If you do parse udisksctl, at least prepend it with LC_ALL=C to avoid localized messages by using the fixed C "virtual" locale, so you at least guarantee the strings matched won't change per user environment.
Examples:

Listing the (writable) partitions with a known filesystem of a drive device (if any):

lsblk "$device" -lnpb --output NAME,RO,FSTYPE | awk '$2 == 0 && $3 {print $1}'


Getting the mountpoint of one such partition above after mounting:

LC_ALL=C udisksctl info -b "$partition" | grep -Po '^ *MountPoints: *\K.*'

No more grepping human-intended messages!
(or, better yet, make your voice heard in this still open 2017 request for a script-friendly interface)
