Does GNU Tar have a single option to get absolutely everything about a tree
I'm in a situation where I want the kind of guarantees of getting every bit of data and metadata about a tree of files that might normally require using dump/restore.  I need everything uids, gids, permissions, hardlinks, attributes, xattrs, and anything else I might not even know about.  And it would save me a lot of effort if I could do this for a tree instead of an image file, so dump is not the preferred path.
Is there any simplified option or set of options for GNU Tar that guarantee it will catch everything?  Or am I stuck with --xattrs-include='*' or --xattrs-include='*.*' and hoping I know everything?

You'll need --xattrs --acls --selinux.
Sadly, GNU tar documentation does not mention any "enable every metadata" option.

I'll take the chance and plug mksquashfs as the better archiver. Archives extended attributes by default, but can't do ACLs as "native" property. However, the archives are, unlike tar archives, mountable on any modern Linux desktop system, and inherently compressed.
As Stéphane points out (and this usenix article confirms), ACLs on Linux are stored in extended attributes, so since mksquashfs stores these, they are fully preserved.
I like the ZFS zfs send backup solution that Stéphane brought up:
sudo zfs send --replicate --holds user/diary@that-snapshot \
     | zstd -10 \
     > backupfile.zfs.zst

That works with XFS as well (say we have an XFS /home volume, and we want to back up /home/user/diary/*)
sudo xfsdump -J -s user/diary - /home \
     | zstd -10 \
     > backupfile.xfs.zst

To restore to a new directory /mnt/externalmedia/user/diary:
zstd -d backupfile.xfs.zst \
    | sudo xfsrestore -J - /mnt/externalmedia


The first part might be the answer when it comes to it.  Squashfs is a little out of scope, but I guess it makes sense: If you can image a disk you can probably mount a disk.

@davolfman you can also extract a squashfs image without root privileges – but then you will not be able to restore file attributes that your user does not control.

@davolfman Ah you might not be aware of my usual "mount a filesystem image without root" method: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775488/udisksctl-get-loop-device-and-mount-point-without-resorting-to-parsing-localize

libarchive's bsdtar, with --format pax (the newer and standard tar format with fewer limitations than the ancient ustar one) will try to preserve all it can and knows about by default which on Linux includes at least:

mtime, atime and even ctime (even if you'll have a hard time restoring that upon extraction) with nanosecond precision
ownership including as name and id
permissions
extended attributes including system ones such as ACL (at least the POSIX draft type ones with names and ids) and SELinux
file flags (as set by chattr)
sparseness
hard links, symlinks
some information about charset used to encode the file names when that can be determined.

If you look at the raw result of bsdtar --format pax -cf - some-christmas-tree-file-with-all-bells-and-whistles,  you'll see things like:
30 ctime=1729146591.860165285
30 atime=1729146640.845221771
30 mtime=1729146591.860165285
24 SCHILY.fflags=sappnd
83 SCHILY.acl.access=user::rw-,group::rw-,other::r--,user:test:r-x:1002,mask::rwx
22 GNU.sparse.major=1
22 GNU.sparse.minor=0
21 GNU.sparse.name=a
31 GNU.sparse.realsize=1048581
61 LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.selinux=dW5jb25maW5lZF91OmZvbwA
51 SCHILY.xattr.security.selinux=unconfined_u:foo^@
30 LIBARCHIVE.xattr.user.x=eQ
25 SCHILY.xattr.user.x=y

Showing it using extensions of all of GNU tar, star and its own.
There are things it can't really know about or that would make no sense to store and may be filesystem specific such as which parts of files are shared between different files for those FS that support reflinks, which parts are transparently compressed by the FS and with which algorithm or are configured to store several copies for redundancy, the order of files in directories for those directories with a flat structure, the inode number, how many links the files have (other than the ones included in the archive), file contents fragmentation, etc.
Whether that's good enough all boils down to what you actually need and care about.
With GNU tar, looks like the best you can get is:
tar --format=pax --sparse --xattrs --acls

Which does include most of the above except for file flags. I find on Linux it stores ACLs both as SCHILY.acl.access (but only with names, no ids) and the raw system extended attribute (so with ids, not names) SCHILY.xattr.system.posix_acl_access while for SELinux context, I see it using SCHILY.xattr.security.selinux only with or without --selinux as long as --xattrs is used.
If using ZFS, you can make a new dataset for the directory, then you can have a faithful archive by taking a snapshot and doing a:
zfs send --replicate --holds pool/path/to/the/dataset@that-snapshot |
   your-favourite-compressor > file

Which should store all possible file data and metadata as well as dataset metadata and which you can restore with zfs recv. If you keep the snapshot around, you can also use -i/-I to do incremental backups later one that only record the difference between the snapshots.

ah, once again, it's the BSD variant of a POSIX-style core utility to the rescue :) And, following your answer, ACLs are represented on Linux as xattrs? Didn't know that! (Makes sense, but shows how little I encountered ACLs in the wild)
